# Azure B2C Password Complexity Requirement - Prevent passwords that contain (parts of) users' username, displayName, etc

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement password complexity in custom policy that will prevent users setting passwords that contain their username, displayname, etc. or contains parts of same (say 5 consecutive characters). What is the best to achieve this?  I am looking at the StringContains TrnsformationType but not sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Implementing Password Complexity in Azure AD B2C to block User's detail in Password is not present as built-in but as we know Custom Policies are very much flexible to implement custom solution.

As per your scenario you can do the following:

1. In the **SelfAsserted** technical Profile where you request to provide Password there in the **ValidationTechnicalProfile** you can add **REST API** technical profile which will check whether the password given by user contains User's detail or not, in the output claim you receive boolean value.
2. Add one more **ValidationTechnicalProfile** of type **ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider** where you include OutputClaimsTransformation of method **AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue**: The following claims transformation demonstrates how to check the value of a **boolean** ClaimType with a value. If the output value of the REST API ClaimType is true and you compared with false, an error message is thrown.

**UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual** self-asserted technical profile metadata
controls the error message that the technical profile presents to the user.

Refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was really looking for something that wouldn't require a REST API call. Is there any chance that exists? I will give this a go regardless and report back.

Comment: As per I am aware string transformation to validate contains between 2 variables is not yet there in B2C, if you don't want to use REST API you can go for CompareClaims Transformation to check the equality instead of contains.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, thanks for your help but the CompareClaims transformation checks for equality but not inclusion.

Comment: I just hit this one and sadly CompareClaims only supports the 'EQUAL' and 'NOT EQUAL'  operators (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#compareclaims?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002618) and as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#using-claim-resolvers?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002618 Claim Resolvers are not supported in InputParameters so it's not possible to use StringContains transformation either. Seems like using secured REST API is the only way to implement such as validation.

Comment: Did anyone ever get this to work?